# Send data from bash CGI to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, bash, post, cgi

I have a PHP script to receive a html/txt data and store it into a MySQL database. The PHP is like this and is in the following path XXX.XXX.XX.158/myphp.php

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['data'];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',''); //DB connection
mysqli_select_db($con,'db1'); //DB selection
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (page) VALUES ($text)";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

On the other hand, I need a BASH-CGI in other local IP (XXX.XXX.XX.157) to send the html/txt file. However, curl is not working for me and I dont know how to do this in pure bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir='Location: ../http/index.html'
#POST($dir) send(data)??
```

Is there any command or method so I can do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try wget? There are two POST options that allows you to send data.

Comment: wget doesnt work neither. I was wondering using exec 3<>/dev/tcp/XXX.XXX.XX.158/80 and think how can i send the data to the php

Comment: please show what you tried with `curl` or `wget` and the result.

Comment: "command not found" for both